# Calling C code with in-memory data from Fortran

Tags: c++, c, memory-management, fortran, fortran-iso-c-binding

I have a complicated C++ object that I'd like to use in my Fortran code.
In general , there is no problem in calling C++ code from Fortran (just need to provide a suitable interface with C linkage for instance).

However my problem here is that I want my Fortran calls to C++ to operate on what I would call a persistent object: a C++ object created by the first init function, and operated on by other C++ functions.

To be more specific, suppose I have the following C++ code

```
struct A {
    public:
      void do() { // do something on complicated stuff
    private:
      ... // complicated stuff
};

extern "C" {
    void* init_A() {
         A* a = new A();
         return reinterpret_cast<void*>(a);
    }

    void doSth(void* ptr_to_A) {
         A* a = reinterpret_cast<A*>(ptr_to_A);
         a.do();
    }

    void teardown_A(void* ptr_to_A) {
         A* a = reinterpret_cast<A*>(ptr_to_A);
         delete a;
    }
}
```

And the following fortran code (suppose it is main() ):

```
USE, INTRINSIC :: ISO_C_BINDING, ONLY: C_PTR
INTERFACE
    TYPE(C_PTR) FUNCTION init_A() BIND(C, NAME='init_A')
        USE, INTRINSIC :: ISO_C_BINDING, ONLY: C_PTR
        IMPLICIT NONE
    END FUNCTION init_A

    SUBROUTINE doSth(ptr_to_A) BIND(C, NAME='doSth')
        USE, INTRINSIC :: ISO_C_BINDING, ONLY: C_PTR
        IMPLICIT NONE
        TYPE(C_PTR), INTENT(IN), VALUE :: ptr_to_A
    END SUBROUTINE doSth

    SUBROUTINE teardown_A(ptr_to_A) BIND(C, NAME='teardown_A')
        USE, INTRINSIC :: ISO_C_BINDING, ONLY: C_PTR
        IMPLICIT NONE
        TYPE(C_PTR), INTENT(IN), VALUE  :: ptr_to_A
    END SUBROUTINE teardown_A
END INTERFACE
```

Now in my real code, this compiles, links, and sometimes works, but sometimes not:
it seems like the memory allocated in init_A() is not garanteed to be left unchanged by the Fortran code)

I wasn't able to find anything about that on the Internet:

- Do you know if there is any standard mechanism to ensure that the memory allocated by init_A_() is left unchanged and still allocated by the fortran code ?
- Do you know of any other mechanism that would suit my problem ?

Also, can someone explain me why the memory is not managed correctly ?
Until now, I thought that

- Fortran would ask the OS for memory, C++ too,
- Memory segments given by the OS to both Fortan and C++ were unrelated and garanteed to be non-overlapping,
- If new memory was asked, the OS would not let Fortran use C++ memory until C++ freed it
- The C++ memory is freed either by a call to teardown_A() or when the program (i.e. Fortran main) terminates

**Edit :** I updated my code with the answer of IanH, but this is still not working (segfaults, portions of memory are deallocated while calling doSth() from Fortran

The original code I posted is the following (for comments refering to it)

```
struct A {
    public:
      void do() { // do something on complicated stuff
    private:
      ... // complicated stuff
};

extern "C" {
    void init_A_(long* ptr_to_A) { // ptr_to_A is an output parameter
         A* a = new A();
         *ptr_to_A = reinterpret_cast<long>(a);
    }

    void doSth_(long* ptr_to_A) {
         A* a = reinterpret_cast<A*>(*ptr_to_A);
         a.do();
    }

    void teardown_A_(long* ptr_to_A) {
         A* a = reinterpret_cast<A*>(*ptr_to_A);
         delete a;
    }
}
```

And the Fortran code:

```
integer :: ptr_to_A

call init_A(ptr_to_A)

do i=1,10000
    call doSth(ptr_to_A)
enddo

call teardown_A(ptr_to_A)
```

Comment: So this question is about C++, not C, right?

Comment: Well except for its C++ syntax, the question is still relevant in C, since only C mechanisms are used (replace new by malloc). I think that C programmers deal with low-level stuff more often and they could know the answer

Comment: `*ptr_to_A = reinterpret_cast<long>(a);` this is undefined behavior as is this `A* a = reinterpret_cast<A*>(ptr_to_A);` The answer by @IanH seems likely to be the correct thing to do since it uses the right types for things on the fortran side and doesn't stuff pointers into `int`s

Comment: I think it is implementation-dependent rather than undefined. I don't like these casts either but I don't expect an interface with Fortran to be nice anyway...

Comment: Do not assume sizeof(long)==sizeof(void*). What size does fortran use for integer? Without knowing fortran, I would guess that your pointer does not fit inside the variable ptr_to_A.

Comment: I don't think this is the case (in my particular implementation at least) since when I print this long in both Fortran and C++, it gives me the same answer

Comment: But thanks to the answer of IanH I now use void*, pass by value and use a return statement in init_A()

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fortran 2003 introduced C interoperability into the Fortran language.  This language feature makes it much easier to write Fortran and C (and hence C++) source that can work together in a portable and robust way.  Unless you are prevented from using this level of the language for other reasons, you should very much use this feature.

You have an issue with pointer indirection - whether the pointer to the C++ object is being stored in a long or a pointer to long (the operand to the casts in doSth_ and teardown_A_ should have a * before them).  It depends on the C++ and Fortran compilers that you are using, but it is possible that you have a size mismatch between a C long, a C pointer and a Fortran default kind integer.

A modified example showing the approach using Fortran 2003's C interoperability feature below.

```
// C++
struct A {
    public:
      void do_something()
      {
         // ...
      }
    private:
      // ...
};

// Note no need for trailing underscore.
extern "C" {
    // Note pointer to pointer to void.
    void init_A(void** ptr_ptr_to_A) {
         A* a = new A;
         *ptr_ptr_to_A = reinterpret_cast<void*>(a);
    }

    void doSth(void* ptr_to_A) {
         A* a = reinterpret_cast<A*>(ptr_to_A);
         a->do_something();
    }

    void teardown_A(void* ptr_to_A) {
         A* a = reinterpret_cast<A*>(ptr_to_A);
         delete a;
    }
}


! Fortran 2003
  USE, INTRINSIC :: ISO_C_BINDING, ONLY: C_PTR
  IMPLICIT NONE
  INTERFACE
    SUBROUTINE init_A(ptr_to_A) BIND(C, NAME='init_A')
      USE, INTRINSIC :: ISO_C_BINDING, ONLY: C_PTR
      IMPLICIT NONE
      ! This argument is a pointer passed by reference.
      TYPE(C_PTR), INTENT(OUT) :: ptr_to_A
    END SUBROUTINE init_A
    SUBROUTINE doSth(ptr_to_A) BIND(C, NAME='doSth')
      USE, INTRINSIC :: ISO_C_BINDING, ONLY: C_PTR
      IMPLICIT NONE
      ! This argument is a pointer passed by value.
      TYPE(C_PTR), INTENT(IN), VALUE :: ptr_to_A
    END SUBROUTINE doSth
    SUBROUTINE teardown_A(ptr_to_A) BIND(C, NAME='teardown_A')
      USE, INTRINSIC :: ISO_C_BINDING, ONLY: C_PTR
      IMPLICIT NONE
      ! This argument is a pointer passed by value.
      TYPE(C_PTR), INTENT(IN), VALUE :: ptr_to_A
    END SUBROUTINE teardown_A
  END INTERFACE
  TYPE(C_PTR) :: ptr_to_A
  INTEGER :: i
  !****
  CALL init_A(ptr_to_A)
  DO i = 1, 100
    CALL doSth(ptr_to_A)
  END DO
  CALL teardown_A(ptr_to_A)
END
```

Comment: Ok thank you very much for your detailed answer. I implemented it and it seems to work now. For future readers: there is also more info about interface at http://stackoverflow.com/tags/fortran-iso-c-binding/info. However, I am still not sure that the 2003 fortran std garantees that my C memory is uncorrupted with this kind of interface declaration. For me, these interfaces were primarily for convenience and portability accross primitive types

Comment: Actually this is not always working. On a more complex case in which the C++ code dynamically allocates more memory in init_A() (I am using a std::vector) I get a segfault in doSth(). Does somebody know how memory is managed by the program/OS in this situation ?

Comment: I have used C_PTR handles to pass C++ objects to Fortran in may different situations.  Your error is probably due to a problem elsewhere.  The C(++) and Fortran standards, between them, guarantee that the above approach works.  (You can replace reinterpret_cast with a static_cast.)

Comment: My bad. I actually did have a reference to a deleted object in my C++ code. Thank you for your answer, you deserve the bounty